# Array Name Storage Program crashing after every input

Tags: c++

Novice C++ user trying to make a program that uses arrays to store names. The output is a menu that you enter a command and it does said function. The problem is that when I attempt to enter a command from the menu, the program crashes. I don't get any errors or warnings when compiling so I'm at a loss for why it crashes.

Any feedback / help is greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Prototypes----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void addName (string nameList[], const int listMax); //Adds a name
void removeName (string nameList[], const int listMax); //Removes a name
void findName (string nameList[], const int listMax); // Searches for a name in the saved list
void showList (string nameList[], const int listMax); //Shows a list of names currentllistMax stored
void sortList (string nameList[], const int listMax); //Sorts saved names in alphabetical order


//Global Declartions--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int listMax = 50;

// MAIN FUNCTION -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(){
    char input; // Variable for when the user inputs their menu selection
    string nameList[listMax]; //string called names with the size being namesMax which is 50


    cout << "Enter a Command " << endl; //Prompt to choose command from menu
    cout << "<A> - Add a name to the database(Max 10)." << endl; //getNames
    cout << "<R> - Remove a name from the database" << endl; //removeName
    cout << "<F> - Search for a name in the database" << endl; //findName
    cout << "<L> - Shows current state of list" << endl; //displalistMaxNames
    cout << "<S> - Sorts the database." << endl; //sortNames
    cout << "<Q> - Ends the program." << endl; //Exits the program entirellistMax
    cin >> input; //Saves the menu choice input 

    if (input == 'A' ||input == 'a') 
        {
            addName(nameList, listMax); 
        }
    else if (input == 'R' || input == 'r')
        {
            removeName(nameList, listMax);
        }
    else if (input == 'F' || input == 'f')
        {
            findName(nameList, listMax);
        }
    else if (input == 'L' || input == 'l')
        {
            showList(nameList, listMax);
        }
    else if (input == 'S' || input == 's')
        {
            sortList(nameList, listMax);
        }
    else if (input == 'Q' || input == 'q')
        {
            return 0; 
        }
}

// ADD NAMES FUNCTION --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void addName(string nameList[], const int listMax){
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < listMax; x++) //x = 0 > if x is less than listMax, increment blistMax 1
    {
        cout << "Enter a name to be added to the database: ";
        cin >> nameList[listMax];
    }
    return;
}

// REMOVE NAMES FUNCTION -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void removeName(string nameList[], const int listMax){
    string clearName; //EmptlistMax String
    string removeName;
    cout << "Enter the name to be removed from the database: ";
    cin >> removeName; //The name entered saved to removeName for further computation

    for (int x = 0; x < listMax; x++) // x = 0, if x is less than listMax; increment blistMax 1
    {
        if(nameList[x] == removeName) // Goes through everlistMax arralistMax level searching to see if it compares to the name saved to removeName
        {
            nameList[x] = clearName; // If name is found, assign value of clearnName, which is an emptlistMax string, thus removing it from the arralistMax.
        }
        else if(x == listMax - 1) // If it goes through the entire arralistMax and doesnt find a match it outputs that the name could not be found.
        {
            cout << "Name not found"; 
        }
    }
    return;
}

// SEARCH FUNCTION -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void findName(string nameList[], const int listMax){
    int x = 0;
    int z;
    bool f = false;
    string searchName;

    cout << "Enter a name to search for";
    cin >> searchName;

    while (!f && x <= listMax) //While f and x are equal to / less than listMax
    {
        int listMax = (x + z) / 2; 
        if (nameList[listMax] == searchName) // if our arralistMax is on level listMax then its on the list
        {
            f = true;
            cout << nameList[listMax] << "is on the list!" <<endl;
        }
        else if (nameList[listMax] > searchName)
            z = listMax - 1;
        else
            x = listMax + 1;
    }
    return;
}

// DISPLAY FUNCTION ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void showList(string nameList[], const int listMax){
    cout << nameList[listMax];
    return;
}

// SORT NAMES FUNCTION -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sortList(string nameList[], const int listMax){
    bool sort;
    do
    {
        sort = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < listMax - 1; x++)
        {
            if (nameList[x] > nameList[x + 1])
            {
                nameList[x].swap(nameList[x+1]);
                sort = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (sort == 1);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: You should share the crash details.

Comment: *I don't get any errors or warnings when compiling so I'm at a loss for why it crashes.* -- A program that compiles with no errors only means that the syntax is correct.  It doesn't mean that your *logic* in the program is correct.

Comment: `cin >> nameList[listMax];`  -- See anything wrong with that line?  That line has perfect syntax, but awful things happen when that line is executed.  That's why believing that no compiler errors means a working program is all wrong.

Comment: Get a good book.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll keep that in mind for my future programs. Thanks. I see the problem was that it had to be `nameList[listMax-1]` instead since arrays start from 0 and not 1. Do I have to change all instances of how I had it?

Answer (score 1):

VisualStudio tells me the code crashes for accessing not-allocated memory.

You use `list[listMax]` several times, which shouldn't be and isn't OK.
The last item in an array `a` with length `len` is `a[len-1]`, not `a[len]` (Because array indices start from 0 in C).

By the way, it also tells me that in `findName()` you use `z` while it's uninitialized, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: I changed `nameList[listMax]` to `nameList[listMax-1]` in `addName`function and now it doesn't crash after that usage. However in `findName` it still crashes, do I change `nameList[listMax]` to `nameList[listMax-1]`  for all of those as well?